# Pandas DataFrame grouping/splitting into smaller DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

We have a question about pandas and DataFrames. We have a large dataset with values that describe 6 different activities (walking, standing, sitting, etc). We are trying to group the values by their activities while perserving their order. Our current DataFrame looks something like this:

```
Walking           0.000181
Standing          0.010139
Standing          0.009276
Sitting           0.005066
Sitting           0.010810
...                    ...
Walking upstairs   -0.356609
Laying             -0.317618
Walking downstairs -0.315016
Walking downstairs -0.330737
Walking upstairs   -0.272348

[470528 rows x 1 columns]
```

What we would like to achieve is (when applied to the example above) 6 different DataFrames. Each only containing the values of 1 activity:

```
Standing   0.010139
Standing   0.009276
```

```
Walking downstairs   -0.315016
Walking downstairs   -0.330737
```

etc

Comment: What have you tried so far based on your own research? [Groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html), [indexing and selecting](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html), other? Please provide a [mcve] showing code for what you've tried so we can better understand how to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a possible (simple) solution

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


index = ["Walking", "Standing", "Standing", "Sitting", "Sitting","Walking upstairs", "Laying", "Walking downstairs", "Walking downstairs", "Walking upstairs"]
arr = np.array([0.000181, 0.010139, 0.009276, 0.005066, 0.010810, -0.356609, -0.317618, -0.315016, -0.330737, -0.272348])

df = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=index)
print(df)

df_walking = df[df.index=="Walking"]
df_standing = df[df.index=="Standing"]
df_sitting = df[df.index=="Sitting"]
df_laying = df[df.index=="Laying"]
df_walking_up = df[df.index=="Walking upstairs"]
df_walking_down = df[df.index=="Walking downstairs"]

print(df_walking)
print(df_standing)
print(df_sitting)
print(df_laying)
print(df_walking_up)
print(df_walking_down)
```